# Subscribe to already mapped Observable in Angular 2 and catch error

Tags: angular, typescript

```
this.userService.saveUser(this.user).subscribe(response => {
```

Given above Code, how can I catch an error when I make use of above returned service, e.g:

I tried:

```
  this.userService.saveUser(this.user)
                .map((res:any) => {
```

which does not work (code execution does halt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is the second parameter in the `subscribe` function.

Your code would be the following:

```
this.userService.saveUser(this.user).subscribe(response => {
       //.. 
 },
 error => {your code});
```

Comment: Very well spotted. Thanks!

Comment: @StephanKristyn you're welcome! You can validate the answer.

Comment: Yes, it takes 5 Minutes to validate. StackOverflow rules. Bonus Question: Is there a `finally` ?

Comment: I think that you could use the third parameter. Here an example: https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-new-http-module-1278499db2a0#.ovb19e28a